# Live Link Smartsheet Cells to Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, smartsheet-api

Looking for a way to sync Smartsheet with a Google Sheet such that they both update in real time.

I have written a Google Apps Script for a Google Sheet.  Trying to avoid going API route.  Im not a developer.

Comment: I haven't tried this but I think [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) bound to a Google Sheet may somehow sync it realtime (may occur some delay). This may not load or function as a realtime sync, but this is the closest to what you want to achieve. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Without using the API directly, you'd need some third party service to handle those calls for you.

Zapier has good Smartsheet integrations that can perform this task.
https://zapier.com/app/editor/template/2558

Another is automate.io, though I have no experience with them:
https://automate.io/integration/google-sheets/smartsheet